# Timer/TimerTask Error

Tags: android, timer, timertask

I just started with programming of android applications and right now I have a problem with timer and timer tasks.

In my app I use a timer to update the UI but when I start to test it gets an error and I have to force close it.

Here is my timer code:

```
int delay = 5000; // delay for 5 sec.
int period = 1000; // repeat every sec.

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        moveLettersInCircle();

    }

}, delay, period);
```

Logcat says this:

```
07-30 18:40:12.635: D/dalvikvm(334): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 61K, 52% free 2599K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 52ms
07-30 18:40:16.186: D/dalvikvm(334): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 36K, 51% free 2672K/5379K, external 3792K/4025K, paused 40ms
07-30 18:40:21.503: W/dalvikvm(334): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-30 18:40:21.526: E/AndroidRuntime(334): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
07-30 18:40:21.526: E/AndroidRuntime(334): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
07-30 18:40:21.526: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2932)
07-30 18:40:21.526: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
07-30 18:40:21.526: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
07-30 18:40:21.526: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
07-30 18:40:21.526: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
07-30 18:40:21.526: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:257)
07-30 18:40:21.526: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
07-30 18:40:21.526: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:257)
07-30 18:40:21.526: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
07-30 18:40:21.526: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.View.setLayoutParams(View.java:5000)
07-30 18:40:21.526: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.jest.womix.Game$1.run(Game.java:104)
07-30 18:40:21.526: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
07-30 18:40:25.666: I/Process(334): Sending signal. PID: 334 SIG: 9
```

How can I solve this ?

Edited HANDLER Code:

```
    Handler m_handler;
    Runnable m_handlerTask;  
    m_handler = new Handler();   
    m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
    {
      @Override 
      public void run() { 

        moveLettersInCircle(); 
        m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000);  //Problem: The local variable m_handlerTask may not have been initialized --> But if I initialize it then I get another error in the line m_handlerTask = new Runnable()

      }
      };
     m_handlerTask.run();
```

Best regards

Comment: post the code of  `moveLettersInCircle();`

Comment: edited my original post

Comment: post you complete class code. you need to declare these as class variables  `Handler m_handler;
     Runnable m_handlerTask;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are updating ui from the backgroudn thread. Timer runs on a different thread.

You should update ui on the ui thread. Use `runOnUiThread`

```
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       // update ui here.
                    }
                });
```

> android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

The above generally means you are updaint/acessing ui from another thread.

You can also use a `Handler`

```
Handler m_handler;
Runnable m_handlerTask ;  
m_handler = new Handler();   
m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
{
  @Override 
  public void run() { 

    // do something  
    m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000);    

  }
  };
 m_handlerTask.run();
```

To cancel the run `m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask)`.

Edit:

```
     timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui thread
                 {
                  public void run() 
                  { 
                    // update ui here
                  }
                  });
            }
        }, 1000, 1000 );
```

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for explaning it :)

so where I have to add the code you posted above ?

Comment: inside your timer task use `runOnUiThread` and call the method or use a handler

Comment: Okay. I'll try it - how can I cancel a timer ?

Comment: use `timer.cancel()`.

Comment: I edited the code of how I uderstood your comment in my main post. I think I got it wrong could you help me ?
And the answer is really nice!

Comment: @user2059411 what is the problem could you be more specific or post the updated logcat

Comment: The problem is thant now I get two errors:

Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
  ConstructorDeclaration
 - Syntax error on tokens, Type expected instead
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
  ConstructorDeclaration
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
  MethodInvocation

Comment: @user2059411 check your closing and opening of braces. those are syntax errors.

Comment: Checked it twice thats why I don't understand the error if you look at the edited code in my main post you can see all braces and all opened braces gets closed.

Comment: Okay but I think using a handler is better, so I changed it now it says it has to be final Handler m_handler; final Runnable m_handlerTask ;

I edit the handler code in my main post

Comment: @Salexes you need to declare those variables as class members to avoid the final modifier. this is very basic.

Comment: Oh sorry yes you are right it is basic I just missed it. My bad.
Now I get no erros right now I'm starting the Emulator to test it.

Comment: With the handler code it works perfectly.
Thank you very much for your patience with my questions etc.