# Android time delay

Tags: android, multithreading, delay

How to make a delay that could call a function after some time but the thread still should be running. Is there any better way than this.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { 
    public void run(){
        try{ Thread.sleep(recordtime); }
        catch(Exception e){}

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                reset();
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: you can use a handler as an alternative

Comment: you can find an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955120/timer-timertask-error/17955219#17955219

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run some code on Ui thread , after some delay:

```
   Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //--code run in Main, UI thread  
        }
    };

    h.postDelayed(r,2000); //-- run after 2 seconds
```

Handler require a `Looper` on target thread. UI thread already has it, other threads need to be configured first.

**Other options are:**

[Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html):

```
  Timer t = new Timer();

    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           //--code run in separate thread  
        }
    },2000);
```

And [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
    ScheduledExecutorService se = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    se.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //--code run in separate thread
        }
    },2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: i haven't tried yet but is it work on some other thread too (not on ui)

Comment: @rikimma Updated with other options.